Sign in options not working on the vercel deployement of next.js App
hi fellow friends i have made an a web application where we can help our students to know from our past interview experinces
link:InterviewXp
i have deployed it using vercel and for backend i have used firebase
now upon deploying the sign in option is not working can some one help me in that?
i tried redeploying the vercel but still the issue was not resolved
